# Using a tree menu beside openlayers

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript

Is there an aplication to add tree menu for the map showed with openlayers?

I mean show a map on my site exactly how is showing in google earth for example, my layers organized in folder/subfolder, with checkboxes.

Comment: Have you looked at geoext layer tree example http://api.geoext.org/1.1/examples/layercontainer.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In OpenLayers this is known as the [Layer Switcher](http://dev.openlayers.org/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Control/LayerSwitcher-js.html). See the [example here](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/layerswitcher.html).

In terms of showing folders and subfolders, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8018958/how-to-add-2-layers-in-a-group says:

> OpenLayers' layer switcher does not support layer hierarchy and will probably never do. I'd recommend checking out the layer tree of MapFish (http://www.mapfish.org). MapFish layer tree is either auto-configured based on the layers configured in OpenLayers or configured through a user-specified model